# Use carousel of materialize via webpack 2

Tags: carousel, materialize, webpack-2

I´m traying use the carusel of materialize via webpack but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function
```

I´m using:

```
"webpack": "^2.2.1"
"jquery": "^3.2.0",
"materialize-css": "^0.98.0"
```

And in my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

I heve checked jquery and css materialize and work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, jQuery v3 is not fully compatible with materialize. A PR is open : https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/pull/4587

Meanwhile, you can change the jQuery in your package.json to match the version used by materialize `"jquery": "^2.1.4"`.